# Crobjob not automatic running in redhat server

Tags: linux, laravel, cron, redhat, kubernetes-cronjob

I have setup cronjob for root user in redhat server environment as follows by typing crontab -e for delete file in storage project

in my laravel project running if i run *php artisan schedule:run*, but not automatic run for every 5 minute,,,   checked for var/log/cron i see cronjob automatic running

[image: var/log/cron]

[image: shcedule:run]

Comment: Try with `php artisan schedule:run`

Comment: ya i try php artisan schedule:run   but data in table still not update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only need to add the following Cron entry to your server

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

More info check [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling)

Comment: how if I use 2 cronjob in 1 Server Redhat?

Comment: you can use what ever number of cronjob. Just you need to schedule every cronjob in your `App\Console\Kernel` class and run above command in your server. More info check https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling#defining-schedules

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

**1. make sure your time (server site) e.g running every 30mnt**

> */30 * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run

**2. make sure your time (laravel site) e.g running at 00:30**

> 30 0 * * *

so if your project (laravel) running with 30mnt (e.g 30 0 * * *) so you must setup server with 30mnt (*/30 * * * *)